# How to assign TRUE or FALSE if a word is present in any of several columns?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, a couple of columns with random data that I do not want to use and 10 columns (column 8:17) containing a variety of different names of actors in several movies, each row is a movie and in column 8:17 the 10 top actors in that movie are named. I want to check whether the name of a certain actor, "Samuel L. Jackson", appears in any of these columns (8:17) for each movie.

I have created an empty column at the end of my data frame.
If the name is present in column 8:17, I want to 1 to be assigned.
If it is not, I want it to be 0.

It's a fairly easy problem it seems, however I have tried lots of different things and none seem to work...

What to do?

I have tried this looping over every row (movie) with an ifelse function, and I have tried the same with seperate if else statements.

```r
for (i in nrow(All_dataset)) {
  All_dataset[i, 18] <- ifelse("Samuel L. Jackson" %in% All_dataset[i, 8], 1, 0)
  All_dataset[i, 18] <- ifelse("Samuel L. Jackson" %in% All_dataset[i, 9], 1, 0)
  All_dataset[i, 18] <- ifelse("Samuel L. Jackson" %in% All_dataset[i, 10], 1, 0)
  All_dataset[i, 18] <- ifelse("Samuel L. Jackson" %in% All_dataset[i, 11], 1, 0)
  All_dataset[i, 18] <- ifelse("Samuel L. Jackson" %in% All_dataset[i, 12], 1, 0)
  All_dataset[i, 18] <- ifelse("Samuel L. Jackson" %in% All_dataset[i, 13], 1, 0)
  All_dataset[i, 18] <- ifelse("Samuel L. Jackson" %in% All_dataset[i, 14], 1, 0)
  All_dataset[i, 18] <- ifelse("Samuel L. Jackson" %in% All_dataset[i, 15], 1, 0)
  All_dataset[i, 18] <- ifelse("Samuel L. Jackson" %in% All_dataset[i, 16], 1, 0)
  All_dataset[i, 18] <- ifelse("Samuel L. Jackson" %in% All_dataset[i, 17], 1, 0)
}
```

```r
for (i in nrow(All_dataset)) {
  if (is.element("Samuel L. Jackson", All_dataset[i, 8]) == TRUE) {
    All_dataset[i, 18] <- 1
  }
  else if (is.element("Samuel L. Jackson", All_dataset[i, 9]) == TRUE) {
    All_dataset[i, 18] <- 1
  }
  else if (is.element("Samuel L. Jackson", All_dataset[i, 10]) == TRUE) {
    All_dataset[i, 18] <- 1
  }
  else if (is.element("Samuel L. Jackson", All_dataset[i, 11]) == TRUE) {
    All_dataset[i, 18] == 1
  }
  else if (is.element("Samuel L. Jackson", All_dataset[i, 12]) == TRUE) {
    All_dataset[i, 18] == 1
  } 
  else if (is.element("Samuel L. Jackson", All_dataset[i, 13]) == TRUE) {
    All_dataset[i, 18] <- 1
  }
  else if (is.element("Samuel L. Jackson", All_dataset[i, 14]) == TRUE) {
    All_dataset[i, 18] <- 1
  }
  else if (is.element("Samuel L. Jackson", All_dataset[i, 15]) == TRUE) {
    All_dataset[i, 18] <- 1
  }
  else if (is.element("Samuel L. Jackson", All_dataset[i, 16]) == TRUE) {
    All_dataset[i, 18] <- 1
  }
  else if (is.element("Samuel L. Jackson", All_dataset[i, 17]) == TRUE) {
    All_dataset[i, 18] <- 1
  }
  else {
    All_dataset[i, 18] <- 0
  }
}
```

Sometimes TRUE is assigned to all of them, sometimes FALSE is, but it is never done correctly (1 for a movie Samuel appears and 0 if he does not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We subset the columns 8:17 in the 'All_dataset' , check if it is equal (`==`) to "Samuel L. Jackson" to return a logical matrix, get the `rowSums`, check if it is greater than 0 to return logical vector, coerce it to binary (TRUE -> 1, FALSE -> 0) with `as.integer` and assign (`<-`) it to the 18th column

```
All_dataset[, 18] <- as.integer(rowSums(All_dataset[, 8:17] ==
          "Samuel L. Jackson") > 0)
```

---

Another option is `Reduce` with `|`.  Loop over the subset of data (`lapply`), return a `list` of logical `vector`s by checking whether the string is present in the column, `Reduce` the `list` to a logical vector with `|` (i.e. checking whether any of the corresponding elements are TRUE), and convert it to a binary as before

```
All_dataset[, 18] <-  as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(All_dataset[, 8:17], 
            `==`, "Samuel L. Jackson")))
```